# How Aspectj driver Hibernate Transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, aspectj

I write AspectJ to automatic driver hibernate Transaction:

```
public aspect HiberAspectj {

    before() :  execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*()) 
             && !cflowbelow( execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*())   )   
             && !within(HiberAspectj) {
        System.out.println("Start hibernate transaction");
    }

    after( ) returning() : execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*()) 
     && !cflowbelow( execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*())   )   
     && !within(HiberAspectj) {
        System.out.println("Commit");
    }

    after() throwing() : execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*()) 
     && !cflowbelow( execution(@AnnHibernateSession * *.*())   )   
     && !within(HiberAspectj) {
        System.out.println("Rollback");
    }
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AnnHibernateSession {

}
```

DAO Class:

```
public class DAO {

    public static void other() {
        System.out.println(" - other");
    }

    @AnnHibernateSession
    public static void updateEmp() {
        System.out.println(" - Update Emp");
    }

    @AnnHibernateSession
    public static void updateDept() {
        System.out.println(" - Update Dept");
    }
}
```

And class Test:

```
public class Test {

    // Call method OK (One Transaction create!!)
    @AnnHibernateSession
    public static void callAction1()  {
        DAO.updateDept();
        DAO.other();
        DAO.updateEmp();
    }

    // No @AnnHibernateSession
    // Call method not OK (2 Transaction Create!!)
    public static void callAction2()  {
        DAO.updateDept();
        DAO.other();
        DAO.updateEmp();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callAction1();
        System.out.println(" ------------------ ");
        callAction2();

    }

}
```

And I run the class Test and get Result:

```
Start hibernate transaction
 - Update Dept
 - other
 - Update Emp
Commit
 ------------------ 
Start hibernate transaction
 - Update Dept
Commit
 - other
Start hibernate transaction
 - Update Emp
Commit
```

Method callAction1 called: one transaction create.

Method callAction2 called: two transaction create (I dont like that).

Help me.
How i can edit aspect HiberAspectj to method callAction2 work like callAction1 ??

Comment: Your aspect does exactly what you specify: It creates a transaction around any method annotated with `@AnnHibernateSession` *except* if a transaction is already open. Because `callAction2` has no transactional annotation, no bracket transaction is created like for `callAction1`. But because both `updateEmp` and `updateDep` bear transactional annotations, transactions are created for each of them. What else do you expect? If you want to change the behaviour, either change the annotations accordingly or modify your aspect. The aspect looks fine though. I recommend to add the missing annotation.